# Colchicine addition to cells

Tags: toxicology, mitosis

1. When is colchicine added to dividing cells for karyotype studies?

I know that colchicine inhibits polymerization of microtubules.

2 So, why should it stop the cell cycle at metaphase when microtubules have already assembled and the next step(anaphase) requires depolymerization rather than polymerization ?

Comment: colchicine is used to synchronize the cells.. so whenever you add it, the cells will eventually be arrested at metaphase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colchicine inhibits the formation of the microtubules by binding to tubilin and rendering it unavailable for the polymerization. Thats why the cells get arrested in the metaphase and can not go on further in the cell cycle and divide. For chromosome studies this is very useful since this is the phase where the chromatin is most condensed and can be viewed best. It inhibits the positive side producing the microtubules to prevent it from moving to the negative side, in cell division.

Comment: I would like to point out that copying from wikipedia without mentioning it as a source is not allowed here.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't looked up this in Wikipedia. Since I have done this stuff myself in the lab I know the background. But I can remove the answer.

Comment: In fact I should say sorry because I thought that I had read that exact lines on wikipedia. I looked it up and you say the same thing but not in the same exact words. I really am sorry , I should not have written the comment without confirming.

Comment: Fine for me, such things happen.

Comment: Thanks. I have one question : I still do not understand why binding tubulin would lead to arrest at metaphase. By metaphase, the whole spindle is complete so why will anything that does not allow polymerization to occur affect this ? Doesn't only depolymerization happen after metaphase ?

Comment: @biogirl When the cells are in the metaphase they have their spindles and can divide. But in cells, which are not, the spindle apparatus can not be build (because the tubulin is not available for it) and the cells get stuck in what I would call early metaphase (there is no further differentiation for this step, so its all called metaphase). The cells get ready for dividing (chromatin gets condensed and so on) but the cells can't go on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12094/discussion-between-biogirl-and-chris)

Comment: @biogirl there is a cell cycle checkpoint for the full formation of the mitotic spindle, and a cell poisoned by colchicine will never pass this checkpoint, hence it will never progress to anaphase.

Comment: @chris When exactly is colchicine added for chromosomal studies ?

Comment: There is no exact timepoint, since the cells are not synchronized in respect to their growth phase. You simply add it to the proliferating cell culture (meaning the cells are still in the growth phase). You can find a protocol [here](http://www.jax.org/cyto/culture_prep.html).